# CPU getting more hash than GPU

Tags: mining-pools, cpu-mining, gpu-mining, mining, mining-hardware

I have Intel Xeon CPU E3-1271 v3 @ 3.60 GHz and a Nvidia Quadro K620 GPU. Windows 7 SP1 OS.

***xmr-stak-cpu*** is giving a hashrate of more than 300 H/s on the CPU.

Whereas ***xmr-stak-nvidia*** is giving hashrate of 111.5 H/s on the GPU.

With null gpu_threads_conf, the xmr-stak-nvidia miner gave me following suggestion:

```
"gpu_threads_conf" : [
{ "index" : 0,
"threads" : 64, "blocks" : 9,
"bfactor" : 6, "bsleep" : 25,
"affine_to_cpu" : false,
},
],
```

When I run the miner with this configuration, the miner crashes and following error pops: nvidia graphics driver stopped responding and has recovered

Then I tuned the parameters. Following is working:
"threads" : 64, "blocks" : 6

Also, threads-32, blocks-12; 
threads-16, blocks-27,24
give same hashrate

and I'm getting hashrate of 111.5 H/s in the miner.

Is this expected? What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to these benchmarks, K620 is supose to get around 120 H/s

http://monerobenchmarks.info/ (threads 32, block 6s)

Also XEON E3-1271 gets 338 H/s

So yes, its probably correct. But you can always tweak it a little bit.